# a method call and avoid the dll not found error all the time if exists

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, reference

This method below is called when you click save all button.
I want to ask you is there any way to skip the error under the code shown below.

Why I ask this: Some times the pDenemeProxy.dll does not exist in the folder of the code.
Morever it is a windows form application. Has the pDenemeProxy.dll in the references. And the fDenemeProxy facade of pDenemeProxy.dll is only initialized if the mDesTemp not null.

Thank you!

```
 private bool SaveAll()
        {
...
..
..
    if (this.mDesTemp != null)
    {           
         fDenemeProxy dnm = new fDenemeProxy();      
         dnm.SaveThisCustomer(1234,"D",true);
    }
...
..
 return;    
}
```

Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'pDenemeProxy, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

note: .net 2.0 and c#
note: Some people advice to put try catch block but it did not work. I have seen during the debug sessions on VS 2008 that when mDesTemp is null we see again the error declared above.

Comment: Just wrap the code with try/catch to catch the FileNotFoundException

Comment: why you dont try to put that code inside try catch block.

Comment: @ I get this error even this.mDesTemp is null... So we have to find another aspect...

Comment: @HansPassant it did not work. please see my comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

In some line in your code you are using a method which throws an `Exception` of type `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` if the conditions for this erroneous situation are true (i.e. you are trying to access a file which is not possible for some reason).

That's the intended and correct behavior what you are experiencing. Whenever you are getting this error message the error has already been happened and now it's up to you to deal with this new situation. That is what `Exception-Handling` is all about.

To deal with an error that was caused by an exception (informally speaking) you would have to catch a exception that has been thrown before (formally speaking).

To do that you have to enclose the portion of code (the actual method call that inheres the throwing of the exception) with a so-called try-catch block like this:

```
private bool SaveAll()
    {
...
..
..
    if (this.mDesTemp != null)
    {       
         try {

             fDenemeProxy dnm = new fDenemeProxy();      
             dnm.SaveThisCustomer(1234,"D",true);

         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

             // deal with the new situation !
         }
    }
...
..
return;    
}
```

The meaning of that is very simple and intuitive:

Inside the `try`-block you are 'securing' a piece of code that is capable of throwing an exception for the case it is doing so. This `try` - block is then followed by an arbitrary number of catch-block - one for each exception that could be thrown by the secured code.

If you have set up this try-catch block correctly you have achieved that whenever your (secured) code throws an exception the execution flow of your program doesn't end (i.e. you program doesn't crash) but it goes to the aproprirate catch-block where you can do anything to deal with error you have just experienced.

Furthermore if you would look on the internet you will find lots of information on that since exception-handling is a very important concept of programming but what I've tried to explain here is the basic concept which you should try to understand first - it won't get more difficult ;)

Comment: @   I get this error even this.mDesTemp is  null... So we have to find another aspect...

Comment: In any case your problem is an exception that has been thrown somewhere. If it hasn't been thrown in the code you've posted above then it is thrown somewhere else.,

Comment: what do you think if it needs to be sure before run the method of SaveAll. I mean if everything is there something like that...

Comment: if `this.mDesTemp` == `null` then control wont proceed further, that's guaranteed. If your control reaches some point below this if-condition you might have either this.mDesTemp not null or another thread is at work. **Do you have a multi-threaded program ? Do you have tried to debug the code step by step ?**

Comment: No I did not but I have very strong logic thay proves this.mDesTemp is null.

Comment: To get over this issue, I replaced the logic that exists on UI side to facade layer. The call of the non-existed method due to the missing dll will be called on facade. And it works. In conclusion, I think that when we call a method, JIT compiler looks for all the necessary methods and its roots existed on the path. Do you Agree with me?